# Unable to read multiple sheets of excel files in a folder in python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read multiple worksheets from 7 different excel files in a folder in python. This is what I have tried -

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# getting excel files from Directory Desktop
path = "Desktop/my_path"

# read all the files with extension
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
print('File names:', filenames)

for f in filenames:
    df_dict = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    df_all = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

The output I am getting is unnamed columns along with some SQL queries.

```
Unnamed: 18
Unnamed: 19
select distinct cal_per_topo from calendrier\n where cal_date_exploit = to_date('01/05/2022','DD/MM/YYYY')\norder by cal_per_topo
```

But the expected output is only the column names with values in it, that is first 18 columns with values

Comment: Add `usecols='A:R'` to your `read_excel` call~

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. While reading my excel, the df_dict is taking all my sheets but also some random SQL queries as columns. But only 4 worksheets exist in my excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it this way?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx")

all_sheets = []
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx"):
    sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    
    for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
        df = pd.read_excel(f)
        sheet['sheet'] = name
        sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
        all_sheets.append(sheet)
        
        all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    
print(all_data)
```